# Динамическая перезагрузка плюсовых dll

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Добрый день.
Есть приложение на C# в которое в процессе работы загружаются managed и unmanaged dll'ки. Необходимо реализовать динамическую перезагрузку этих dll'ок. C managed dll'ками проблем не возникает - я создаю дополнительный домен и загружаю их в него, а потом выгружаю весь домен. Unmanaged dll'ки, как я понимаю, с доменом не взаимодействуют и нужен другой механизм. Я пробовал освобождать их и загружать снова при помощи:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

Но при попытке повторного использования классов из этих библиотек бросается исключение Access Violation. Подозреваю, что при использовании FreeLibrary библиотеки выгружаются, но в clr остаются указатели на них и при попытке использования бросается исключение.

Вопрос: есть ли какой-то способ осуществить выгрузку и повторную загрузку unmanaged dll и в дальнейшем использовать их.

Comment: А вам обязательно делать `FreeLibrary`? Может оставить dll-ки в памяти?

Comment: Необходимо реализовать обновление этих длл без перезагрузки программы. Для этого и нужно выгрузить их из памяти.

Comment: "clr остаются указатели на них" - на них это не на библиотеки. это на участки памяти, классы, привязки к дескрипторам и т п. Вам нужно при освобождении анулировать/освободить все обьекты которые содержат ссылки полученые этой библиотекой. Либо делайте список таких обьектов (освобождайте/блокируйте весь список), либо как-то по другому проверяйте валидность обьектов.

Comment: Приведите пример обьектов которые зависят от этих библиотек, тогда будет понятно где вы теряете ссылки/обьекты и можно будет дать более конкретные рекомендации.